# git reset --soft <commit-id>

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I have to go back to 10 commits back in my local git repo.

So, in between I have 9 commits, are they revert if I go back to 10th commit. These 9 commits in between are done by others. Will they get affect by this?

Comment: Draw the commit history you have, with labels on the commits. Then draw the history you want, with any new/rewritten commits, and remarks on what you want in them.  Then ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it only on your local, no. If you want to push changes they will definitely get affected. If all you want is to remove one commit, you can use `git revert` to achieve that.

Comment: If I push it to remote, it will go back to HEAD^10 and our code will be 10 commits behind?

Comment: Yes, even if you do a rebase and remove the commit, the commit ids of the other 9 will change and your team mates will have to reset their branch. If that is okay, you can proceed with it. But revert is a better way to achieve it

Comment: Actually, I changed 4 files under 10Th commit (Behind), but my colleagues changed them.Mean while other folks worked on some other files and pushed to remote. I want the old state of the 4 files I changed (i.e 10 commits behind).
git reset --soft <commit-id> will take HEAD back to 10 commits. But, not git revert --soft <commit-id>. Right?

Comment: @MadEngineer, in essence, but the commands aren't like that. Checkout this tutorial for a better understanding of `git revert` and `git reset`.

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` command operates on a branch. If you have a local branch checked out only this (and your local `HEAD`) will be affected. If you push the branch to a remote branch, the remote branch will be affected. If you are detached when resetting (no branch checked out), only your local `HEAD` is affected.